# How to plot a datafile with different binary marks or colors with GNUPlot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

We need to plot a data file like this:

2986.101193, -1.000000

2986.691195, -1.000000

2986.249106, -1.000000

2987.982243, 1.000000

2987.876890, -1.000000

2987.918132, 1.000000

...

and we need to have the first real number in the Y-axis and the label (-1, 1) as a color, or different mark sign.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any search on the gnuplot homepage or for tutorials? Where is your script attempt? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: With gnuplot:
plot "s.txt"
with s.txt the file described above, but we don't get the desired plot.

Comment: Ok, well, this is too little. Have you tried to consult a basic gnuplot tutorial? What should the x-axis be, just the line number? Is there really an empty line between all data lines or is it just a formatting issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the manual or type in the console the following:
`help ternary`, `help pointtype`, `help lc variable`.
Type `test` to see the different pointtypes (e.g. 9=filled triangle up, 11=filled triangle down, etc.).
For the colors check `help colorspec`.

- you can set variable pointtype (`pt var`)
- you can set variable linecolor with RGB colors (`lc rgb var`)
- define functions using the ternary operator `a ? b : c`

**Script:**

```
### plot with variable pointtype and color
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2986.101193, -1.000000
2986.691195, -1.000000
2986.249106, -1.000000
2987.982243,  1.000000
2987.876890, -1.000000
2987.918132,  1.000000
EOD

set datafile separator comma
myPt(col)    = column(col)<0 ? 11 : 9
myColor(col) = column(col)<0 ? 0xff0000 : 0x00ff00
set grid x,y
set offsets graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1

plot $Data u 0:1:(myPt(2)):(myColor(2)) w p pt var lc rgb var ps 3 notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]